# SQL order by on UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a  query as bellow :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[start_of_week],103) AS WEEK_START, VisitorCount FROM mytable2
UNION 
SELECT 'Average' AS WEEK_START,AVG(VisitorCount) from mytable2
ORDER BY WEEK_START
```

If I run the top query I get all sorted as the WEEK_START but when I Union the query for 'Average' the sort order gets messed up.
Can anybody please let me know how can I have all the WEEK_Start sorted and the 'Average' be at the end ?

**UPDATE**
The complete query is

```
DECLARE @From DATE = '2015-07-01'
DECLARE @To DATE = (SELECT GETDATE())
DECLARE @dt DATE = '1905-01-02';
WITH mytable as(
SELECT 

    1 as visitor,
    DATEDIFF(week, '', date) AS WeekNumber,
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, @dt, [Date]), @dt) AS [start_of_week]
    FROM Showroom_perf
    Where [Date] <= @To

) , mytable2 AS ( 
Select 
[start_of_week],
COUNT(visitor) as VisitorCount
from mytable WHERE WeekNumber > '0'
GROUP BY
[start_of_week]

)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[start_of_week],103) AS WEEK_START, VisitorCount, 1 as tag FROM mytable2 
UNION 
SELECT 'Average' , AVG(VisitorCount), 2 as tag  from mytable2
```

And following is the result I see :
[image]

Comment: The first query is a set, the second query is another set. You UNIONed two sets and set doesn't have an order. There is no way to achieve this except adding a new column specifying from which sub query each item(row) is from.

Comment: tried adding a column ad that even doesn't working for me. Please see the bellow answers.

Comment: @marifrahman Changed my answer to remove the additional column.

Comment: @marifrahman, you only need extra column in `ORDER BY` instead of `SELECT` clause, right?

Comment: `WEEK_START` contains either date values in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, or the string literal `'Average'`. Hence sorting should work as it is, placing all date values at the top and `'Average'` at the bottom.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: If I do not use the Average query - the dates are sorted ok - only issue is if I Union the Average query.

Comment: In this case, I think I have misunderstood your actual requirements. Can you please post the *required* resut set (right below the result you get)?

Comment: All the dates sorted

Answer (score 4):

A better way do it

Use [ROLLUP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Grouping(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), start_of_week, 103)) = 1 THEN 'Average'
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), start_of_week, 103)
       END AS WEEK_START,
       Avg(VisitorCount)
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), start_of_week, 103) WITH rollup 
Order by start_of_week
```

- [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4508)

Comment: I think you should change the group by condition for the proper ordering [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4470)

Comment: Tried this solution with same result.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a new column for order and give a different value to each part of union. Since you cannot add an additional column to the output, you can use a CTE to remove it later:

```
WITH temp as (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[start_of_week],103) AS WEEK_START, VisitorCount, 1 as Ord
    FROM mytable2
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Average' AS WEEK_START,AVG(VisitorCount), 2 as Ord
    from mytable2
)
SELECT WEEK_START, VisitorCount
FROM temp
ORDER BY Ord, WEEK_START
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49683/7) (a simplified example)

Comment: nah - not working and adding an extra column is not an option for me.

Comment: Fair enough with not adding an extra column but what is not working?

Comment: The sorting with the WEEK_START not working- even if I try adding the column u suggested.

Comment: The demo you have provided is working great - but strangely not working for me !! For your demo I tired even without  order by and its sorting correctly !!

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy column in `SELECT` clause to specify Order By.
Below I have used a column named `tag` for this purpose.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[start_of_week],103) AS WEEK_START, VisitorCount FROM mytable2, 1 as tag
UNION 
SELECT 'Average' AS WEEK_START,AVG(VisitorCount),2 from mytable2
ORDER BY tag,WEEK_START
```

So first order by will work on tag column pushing top query result to top and then sorting done on query below `UNION` operator.

Comment: u want to remove extra column ?